# Is it possible to specify an optional return type and deduce it if unspecified?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to have a transformation-function, which applies some algorithm to a parameter and returns the transformed result. It doesn't necessarily have to change the return type, however, so I would like to give the caller the option of leaving out the return type specification and let the compiler deduce it from the input type.

(Simplified) Example:

```
template <typename Ret = In, typename In, typename Func>
Ret transform(const In& in, Func f)
{
    return f(in);
}
```

I want to call it like this:

```
auto result = transform(inValue, transformation); // 1
auto differentResult = transform<DifferentType>(inValue, transformation); // 2
```

Keep in mind this is simplified. In reality I pass `f` onward to `std::transform` and the `In` and `Ret` types are containers of some sort. Therefore I cannot use the result of `f` or some other magic to determine the return type. Of course the provided example won't work because this

```
typename Ret = In, typename In
```

is illegal. If I do it the other way round:

```
typename In, typename Ret = In
```

it will do exactly what I want in case 1. However I will have to specify the input type for case 2:

```
auto differentResult = transform<InType, DifferentType>(inValue, transformation);
```

This is mainly a convenience issue, if there is no way to do it, so be it. It seems I would need some sort of trailing template type specifier :)

**The real code**

```
template <typename Ret, typename In, typename Func>
Ret transform(const In& input, Func func)
{
    Ret output{};
    std::transform(std::cbegin(input), std::cend(input), std::inserter(output, std::end(output)), func);
    return output;
}
```

With the above form I always have to specify a return type. I'm just wondering if there is a way to deduce it from `input` if no template argument for `Ret` is given.

EDIT: It works if I provide two overloads, one using 2 template arguments, the other using 3. I am still wondering if it is somehow possible to do this using one function only.

Comment: Could you please show the body of the function?

Comment: Ever heard of template argument deduction?

Comment: @Jefffrey I did - it's in the example. Or do you want to see the real code? I didn't want to include it because it will only distract from the real question.

Comment: @Excelcius, the real code, please.

Comment: @Paranaix This question is all about argument deduction. And I understand how argument deduction works. The problem here is the order of the template arguments. If I want to automatically deduce the return type from the input type the second call to transform won't work because I'm specifying the Input type, not the return type.

Comment: @Excelcius Well your attempt `typename Ret = In` shows me that you doesnt understand, besides that, c++11 features `auto` return type and `decltype` now

Comment: @Paranaix I know that this won't work. But this is what I want to accomplish somehow. Another way to explain it: I want to either provide no template arguments or just the first when calling. If no arguments are supplied I want the first one to be the same as the (deduced) secone one.

Comment: @Paranaix How does a trailing return type or decltype help here? I want to make it dependent on the way it's called. If I always return the decltype of `in` I'm not able to override the return type as the caller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d75e57914794afa), with simple function overloading :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const & vec ) {
    for( auto & e : vec )
        os << e << " ";
    return os;
}

template <typename Ret, typename In, typename Func>
Ret transform_copy( In const& input, Func&& func) {
    Ret output{};
    std::transform( std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::inserter(output, std::end(output)), std::forward<Func>(func) );
    return output;
}

template <typename In, typename Func>
In transform_copy( In const& input, Func&& func) {
    return transform_copy<In,In,Func>(input, std::forward<Func>(func));
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "abc";

    auto r0 = transform_copy( str, [](char b) { return b+1;} );
    std::cout << r0 << "\n";

    auto r1 = transform_copy<std::vector<int>>( str, [](char b) { return b+1;} );
    std::cout << r1 << "\n";

    auto r2 = transform_copy<std::string>( r1, [](char b) { return b+1;} );
    std::cout << r2 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added this to the question right away. I know that this will work, I was wondering if there's a way to do it without the overload. I'll wait a bit if others come up with a different idea. If nobody does I'll accept this as the answer since it's the obvious way to work around the issue.

Comment: @Excelcius: not though, that even though there are two overloads, there is a single *implementation* because the simpler overload just passes up the work to the more complex one.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes of course, that's the only real way to do it. I'm already using this approach in my code I just thought it won't hurt to ask, there are always some C++11-features I'm not aware of which might simplify this even more.

Comment: @Excelcius: well, I can think of putting the `Ret` parameter last, so it could have a default; but that's not exactly satisfying. There may be better, however, it's hard to prove something does not exist after all :)